# Stepping through foldr

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

How does one step through this in racket? I wrote a piece of code and it seems to work just fine. However, I don't understand it.

(source : uwaterloo CS Fall 2015 Assignment 09 which was due on Nov 24)

The question is : Write a function `unique-fn` that consumes a list and a predicate equality function and produces the same list
such that all duplicates, according to the provided equality predicate, are removed. No sorting or recursion may be used. For example,

```
 (check-expect (unique-fn '(3 1 3) =) '(3 1))

 (check-expect (unique-fn '(1 1.05 2 1.2) 
                          (lambda (x y) (> 0.1 (abs (− x y))))) 
              '(1 2 1.2))
```

Here is my code which works but I don't understand how :

```
(define (unique-fn list-of-elm pred?)
(foldr (lambda (x y)
       (cons x (foldr (lambda (a b) 
               (cond[(pred? x a) b]
                    [else (cons a b)])) empty y)))
     empty list-of-elm))
```

I really don't know how to step through this. I know foldr folds from the right but how does this "nested" foldr actually work? Any thoughts?

Comment: Because the `foldr` in your code calls itself. It is using recursion and does not meet the requirements as stated in your question.

Comment: `(foldr f z [a,b,...,n]) == (f a (f b (...(f n z)...)))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to thing of `foldr` procedure argument as taking formal parameters `(x acc)` instead of `(x y)` In this case you are accumulating a list so a cons is appropriate opening to that procedure.

However I don't think this is a foldr, I think its a foldl. If it were a foldr, you would have 1.05 in `acc` before you call the prodedure and would keep 1.05 and throw out 1. The logic actually reads left to right, the leftmost duplicate is preserved, and the rightward duplicates removed.

```
(define (unique-fn list-of-elm pred?)
 (reverse ;for right result order
   (fold (lambda (acc x)
            (if (member x acc pred?) ;member optionally accepts a predicate
                acc
                (cons x acc)))
         empty 
         list-of-elm)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Racket's stepper? It looks to me like your code should run fine in one of the teaching languages, perhaps Intermediate. The stepper should show you every step of the program's evaluation.